# Source information is missing from the debug information for this module (for free function)

Tags: c, visual-studio, free

I'm debugging a (.c) project in VS 2019. when I reach `free` function I receive this message(same for (.cpp)):

> **Source not available**
>
> Source information is missing from the debug information for this
>   module
>
> You can view disassembly in the Disassembly window. To always view
>   disassembly for missing source files, change the setting in the
>   Options dialog.

can some please tell me what should I do?

Comment: Ignore it? Unless you're actually debugging that memory allocation implementation, you shouldn't need to step into the function. What's usually actually important is where you're calling it.

Comment: Instead of Step Into, use Step Over.